# Can't get State Restoration to work with Programmatic Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, programmatically-created, state-restoration

I'm unable to get State Restoration working with a Navigation Controller. I am using Swift and do not want to use Storyboards (Programmatic). Almost all the help I've found online is either not in Swift or using Storyboards.

In the demo code below, ViewController contains a simple PickerView, and a `selection` variable keeps track of the Picker selection. The AppDelegate is presented with 2 options.  With **Option 1**, no Navigation Controller is used and the state of the Picker is restored fine, but is not restored with the Navigation Controller in **Option 2**. (In the code below, Option 1 is commented out and Option 2 is active).

You can copy & paste the code below into a fresh singleView application and it should reproduce what I've described. (I tested it)

*AppDelegate Code:*

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let pickerVC = ViewController()
    //Option 1: No NavC used
    //window?.rootViewController = pickerVC

    //Option 2: NavC used
    let navC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: pickerVC)
    navC.restorationIdentifier = "PickerNav"
    window?.rootViewController = navC

    return true
  }

//  func application(_ application: UIApplication, viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath identifierComponents: [Any], coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
//    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
//      if let lastItem = identifierComponents.last as? String {
//        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: lastItem)
//      }
//    return nil
//  }
}
```

*ViewController Code:*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

  var pickerView: UIPickerView!
  var selection = 0
  let group = ["Fruit","Vegetable","Meat","Bread"]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    restorationIdentifier = "PickerVC"
    setupPicker()
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    pickerView.selectRow(selection, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
  }

  override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(selection, forKey: "selection")
    super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
  }

  override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    selection = coder.decodeInteger(forKey: "selection")
    super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
  }

  func setupPicker() {
    pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(pickerView)

    pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pickerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
  }

  func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return group.count
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selection = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26)
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    pickerLabel.text = group[row]
    pickerLabel.textColor = .white
    return pickerLabel
  }
}
```

**Details of my testing:** With Option 1, changing the Picker followed by *cmd-Shift-H* causes the `selection` variable to be saved in `encodeRestorableState`. I then click the Xcode *Stop* button and then run it again, and the `selection` variable is restored in `decodeRestorableState`. By contrast, with Option 2
State restoration does not work because `decodeRestorableState` is never called so the `selection` variable is not restored. However, a breakpoint at `viewDidAppear` shows that `navigationController?.restorationIdentifier` = "PickerNav" and `restorationIdentifier` = "PickerVC"

From what I've read, I suspect I may need to use  `viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath` in AppDelegate, but I didn't know how to use it correctly.  My attempt at the bottom of AppDelegate (the code is commented out) causes the app to crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extension to your ViewController and make it conform to protocol `UIViewControllerRestoration` and implement the `viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath` method.
In the `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` function add `restorationClass` just like `restorationIdentifer` like

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        restorationIdentifier = "PickerVC"
        restorationClass = ViewController.self
        setupPicker()
    }


extension ViewController: UIViewControllerRestoration {

    static func viewController(withRestorationIdentifierPath identifierComponents: [Any], coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
        let vc = ViewController()
        return vc
    }

}
```

Add this code in your ViewController class and delete the `viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath` method that you have added in `AppDelegate`

Comment: This worked -- thanks! I'm unclear why things worked fine without a restoration class before the Navigation Controller and then required a restoration class with a Navigation Controller. According to the documentation, "If the view controller did not have a restoration class, UIKit asks the app delegate to provide the view controller [using viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath]...If that method returns nil, UIKit tries to find the view controller implicitly".  Not sure which is happening in this case?  Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @TonyM cool that it worked. I'm also unaware of why is it happening so :(